# Usigned char goes over 255

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I would like to use an `unsigned char` as a byte. I would expect that it would have a range from `0` to `255`.

I defined the following macro:

```
#define ROTATE_LEFT(BYTE) ((BYTE & 128) > 0) ? ((BYTE << 1) | 1) : (BYTE << 1)
```

I would like to rotate it to the left.

Now I tested it by:

```
unsigned char c1 = 1;
unsigned char c2 = 128;
unsigned char c3 = 255;
unsigned char c4 = 200;
printf("%u\n", ROTATE_LEFT(c1)); // Expected: 2, Result: 2
printf("%u\n", ROTATE_LEFT(c2)); // Expected: 1, Result: 257
printf("%u\n", ROTATE_LEFT(c3)); // Expected: 255, Result: 511 
printf("%u\n", ROTATE_LEFT(c4)); // Expected: 145, Result: 401
```

As you can see, I get results that should't be even possible.
What is wrong?

Comment: Actually it not undefined behaviour, see answer below. But anyway "undefined behaviour" is a concept you should get familiar with if you are programming in C.

Comment: If you want to use fixed-size types then check out `<stdint.h>`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Actually it is. Beacuse an `int` is passed and an `unsigned` is expected.

Comment: @MortenJensen: Actually, he should use `inttypes.h`, too for the format string.

Comment: @Olaf passing an `int` to `printf("%u"...` is not UB when the value is representable as both `int` and `unsigned`.  C11 §6.5.2.2 6 overrides §7.21.6.1 9.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This because of *integer promotion*.

Your results are bring promoted to larger integers before being passed to printf.

You could store the result back into your variable, before passing that variable to printf. They will necessarily be truncated.

Also, the `printf` specifier for an `unsigned char` is `%hhu`.

Finally, I would suggest the following (untested) instead:

```
static inline uint8_t rol8(uint8_t x)
{
    uint8_t low = (x & (1<<7)) >> 7;
    return (x << 1) | low;
}
```

Comment: no, it is not before passing to printf, it is while the unsigned expression is evaluated . Try `printf("%zu\n", sizeof ( ROTATE_LEFT(c2))) ; `

Comment: I didn't expect this to happen. Thanks

Comment: It looks valid. As with any code, write some unit tests to prove it is correct for all corner cases, and that it *stays correct* as things change.

Comment: @DennisvonEich No, it is not correct. You should always parenthesise the macro arguments when you use them inside the macro: `#define ROTATE_LEFT(BYTE) (((BYTE) & 128) > 0) ? (((BYTE) << 1) | 1) : ((BYTE) << 1)` This is beacuse the macro can be called with any expressing. Try for instance: `ROTATE_LEFT(c1 + c2);`

Comment: Always prefer static inline functions over macros.

Comment: @DennisvonEich it was part of the linus/SCO errno.h affair. (LBT excused himself for this oversight)

Comment: While this works and is correct, I think it is good practice to use unsigned integers only for shifting, e.g. `1U << ...`. That way border-cases will not cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: Candidate code simplification `return (x << 1) | (x >> 7);`

Answer (score 0):

Just like this:

```
unsigned char c4 = 200;
printf("%u\n", c4 + 56);
```

output: `256`

It's nothing to do with the `unsigned char` type of `c4`, you just pass a greater-than-255 value to `printf` function.